# rails 3 increment a related model attribute before/after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, increment

I have a basic app that allows user1 to create a redeemable code.  user1 shares this code with his friends and user2,3,4 redeem the code.  At each redemption I need to to increment user1's points attribute.

the first time a user redeems the code, it creates a redemption. this never works again as the user can only redeem a code once.  another user can redeem it, but not more than once each.

So I figured I would use a before or after_create callback.  Here is my redemption class:

```
class Redemption < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :code
  belongs_to :user

  validates :code_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  before_create :increment_points

  def increment_points
    self.user.increment(:points)
  end 

end
```

I tried this, and it did not return any errors, it handled the redemption but did not increment points...

ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Benjamin said above. Increment does not save the model. Increment! does.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with you not saving the user model. Something like `self.user.save!` might do the trick.

Comment: that did it to but simply adding a bang is more elegant.